# How do you open a file from inside a module inside a package with a relative path?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to have a module inside a package open a txt file inside its directory and read its contents.

This is what my arrangement looks like:

```
package
|  __init__.py
|  bar.py
|  baz.py
|  txt.txt

foo.py
```

This is the content of `txt.txt`

```
a()
```

This is the content of `baz.py`

```py
def a():
    with open("txt.txt") as file:
        print(file.read())
```

This is the content of `bar.py`

```py
from .baz import a
def b():
    a()
    print("b()")
```

This is the content of `__init__.py`

```py
from .bar import b
def c():
    b()
    print("c()")
```

This is the content of `foo.py`

```py
from package import c
c()
```

When running foo.py I expected to get

```
a()
b()
c()
```

but instead I got this error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 2, in <module>
    c()
  File "(...my full path...)\package\__init__.py", line 3, in c
    b()
  File "(...my full path...)\package\bar.py", line 3, in b
    a()
  File "(...my full path...)\package\baz.py", line 2, in a
    with open("txt.txt") as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'txt.txt'
```

I changed the argument of the `open` function, `"txt.txt"`, to the full path and it worked, but that is not really useful because I must use a relative path, and I don't understand what's going on.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `foo.py` is being run from a location where the relative path `text.txt` doesn't exist. If `foo.py` is being run from the same location as `package` directory, use `package/text.txt` as the file path. Remember: what determined the path is your code is running, not where the code being run is located.

Comment: If you have troubes with relative paths, use absolutes. The `__file__` attribute of a modules in combination with `pathlib` or the functions in `os.path` might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, paths are relative to the calling script in this case `foo.py`.

If you want to read `txt.txt` from calling `foo.py` you will need to modify `baz.py` like so

```py
def a():
    with open("package/txt.txt") as file:
        print(file.read())
```

Alternatively you can retrieve the package path using [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) and [`sys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules) like so

```py
import os
import sys
def a():
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.modules[__name__].__file__),"txt.txt")) as file:
        print(file.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either set your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to point to your package or you can address `txt.txt` relative to where you are running `foo.py`

for the first option you can do as follow:
`PYTHONPATH=path/to/package python foo.py`
for second option first change your directory to package then run `foo.py`